# I have created module but checkbox not working properly in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkbox

[image] have create module all filed work properly but checkbox **edit time not checked automatically**.

```
$fieldset->addField('hobbies[]', 'checkboxes', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('contactform')->__('Checkboxs'),
            'name' => 'hobbies[]',
            'values' => array(
                array('value' => 'read', 'label' => 'read'),
                array('value' => 'write', 'label' => 'write'),
                array('value' => 'games', 'label' => 'games'),
            ),
            'value' => array('read', 'games'),
             'disabled' => array('1'),
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
//$selected = array('read', 'games');
$selected = 'get value here from database format as above';

    $fieldset->addField('hobbies', 'checkboxes', array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Checkboxs'),
                'name' => 'hobbies[]',
                'values' => array(
                    array('value' => 'read', 'label' => 'read'),
                    array('value' => 'write', 'label' => 'write'),
                    array('value' => 'games', 'label' => 'games'),
                ),
                'checked' => $selected,
            ));
```

Comment: thank you ...but checkbox edit time not checked automatically

Comment: updated code check it

Comment: how to get value here from database format as above

Comment: add your form code

Comment: what the form code

Comment: Form file which contain your posted code in question post this file code here

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in admin form

```
$model = Mage::registry('authorize_data');
    $fieldset->addField('hobbies[]', 'checkboxes', array(
                            'label'     => 'hobbies',
                            'name'      => 'hobbies[]',
                            'values' => array(
                                array('value'=>'aaa','label'=>'Checkbox1'),
                                array('value'=>'bbb','label'=>'Checkbox2'),
                                array('value'=>'ccc','label'=>'Checkbox3'),
                            ),
                            'checked' => unserialize($model->getHobbies())
                        ));
```

and in save action 
use this code

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$postData['hobbies'] = serialize($postData['hobbies']);
```

store this serialize array in your field